# Does anyone know of a decent JavaScript portal?

Tags: javascript, portal

I'm looking for a JavaScript portal but the ones I've found so far haven't been very good. Here's what I've found:

**jPolite**

http://trilancer.wordpress.com/jpolite/

This one, inexplicably, seems to be the most popular. It's super sluggish and doesn't even seem to work right, though.

**jQuery Portlets**

http://host.sonspring.com/portlets/

This one is okay but I'm a little turned off by the ZERO documentation. I can't even figure out where the main code is.

What I'm looking for is something more like iGoogle, where the portlets can be variable height. A LITTLE documentation would be nice, too. Does nothing like this exist?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: There's no programming question here.

Comment: You need to specify why you need this and how it is programming related or this is questions is going to get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **jQuery UI**

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for a framework, not a library

Comment: I think you meant [jQuery UI Portlets demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets)

Answer (score 1):

Docking Boxes is pretty cool, have never used because I haven't had the need but it looks worth while.

http://brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/dbx/

Answer (score 1):

portal component from ExtJS 4 is very complete flexible, long learning curve though

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/portal/portal.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this jQuery plugin? http://masonry.desandro.com/

I have played around with it sometime before aiming to create a user interface similar to http://pinterest.com/. I found it quite easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

There are some more JS portals:

- [DojoX Portlets in GridContainer](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/widget/Portlet.html#portlets-in-a-grid-container), using Dojo Toolkit
- [jPolite2](http://code.google.com/p/jpolite2/), second version of the jQuery plugin
- [YUI Portal Style](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/portal-drag.html), demo using YUI3 Drag&Drop
- [jQuery UI Portlets](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets), demo using jQuery UI Sortable
- [DropThings](http://code.google.com/p/dropthings/), using jQuery and ASP.NET
- [Drupal Portal](http://aymanh.com/drag-drop-portal-interface-with-scriptaculous), using Scriptaculous and Drupal